# MongoDB : use string manipulation in aggregation pipeline

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a little app built with NestJS latest and i'm using Mongoose v5.

I have filled the database with 500+ jobs references.
I writed a search function with aggregation pipeline to match the correct elements from my collection :

```js
const query = await this.jobsModel.aggregate([
        { $match : { name: { $regex: jobName, $options: 'i' } }},
        { $project : { id:1, name:1, familyId:1, familyColor:1, svgListIcon:1, _id:1}},
        { $addFields : { searchName : this.createSearchName('$name') }},
        { $sort : { 'name': 1 }},
      ])
  
return query;
```

And i would like to parse each $name field to use a regex and replace all \r\n from $name field :

```js
createSearchName(jobName) {
    return jobName.replace(/\r\n/," ");
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work because the .replace() doesn't take the jobName parameter, and only using '$name'...

What is the correct way to achieve this action ?

Do i need to do 1 query, parse the result, then do an aggregation pipeline ?

Comment: If you are using MongoDB 4.4, then you can use the _new_ aggregation operator [replaceAll](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceAll/).

Comment: Awesome... Thank you so much! Just updating from 4.2 to 4.4 and this operator is exactly was i'm trying to do ! have a good day :) You can make an answer and i'll accept it.

Comment: I dont have access to 4.4. You can post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @prasad_, i updated MongoDB from 4.2 to 4.4 and i'm using the new operator [replaceAll](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceAll/).
This operator work as an .replace() on the query.

This is my new aggregation pipeline :

```js
const query = await this.jobsModel.aggregate([   
        { $match : { name: { $regex: jobName, $options: 'i' } }},
        { $project : { id:1, name:1, familyId:1, familyColor:1, svgListIcon:1, _id:1}},
        { $addFields : { searchName : { $replaceAll: { input: '$name', find: '\r\n', replacement: ' '}} }},
        { $sort : { 'searchName': 1 }}
]);
```